# Finding the matrix of the adjoint transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following exercise:

Let $B=\{b_1,b_2\}$ a orthonormal basis of a Euclidean space $V$. Let $C=\{b_1,b_1+b_2\}$, and the matrix of $f:V\to V$ with respect to $C$ is:
$$A_{f,C}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
If we let $f^*$ be the adjoint transformation, find $A_{f^*,C}$. My attempt:

We know that the relation with of the basis is given by $C=BT$ with $T$ the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}$. Also we know that $A_{f,C}=T^{-1}A_{f,B}T$, and therefore $A_{f,B}=TA_{f,C}T^{-1}$, this is:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 \\ 1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}, $$
Now, as $B$ is orthonormal, we have $A_{f^*,B}=A_{f,B}^*=\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 1 \\ -1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$. Now, we conjugate with $T$ to change the basis:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 1 \\ -1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -2 \\ -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

This is the procedure that is more logical to me, but I have are two questions:

1. This is ok? I think the calculations are ok, but my professor told us that the answer was $\begin{pmatrix}
   3 & 6 \\ -1 & -3
   \end{pmatrix}$, but i don't know why.

2)I can notice that the matrix was exactly the adjoint of the initial matrix $A_{f,C}$, so, this implies that in this problem I just needed to calculate de adjoint matrix of this? Or is this just a coincidence?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you changed basis back to $B$, you wrote:

> Now, as B is orthonormal, we have $A_{f∗,B} = A^∗_{f,B} = \begin{pmatrix} −2 & 1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$.

This was not correct. You switched the signs on the diagonal entries of the matrix. This is not the transpose of the matrix you had on the line before. It should instead be $\begin {pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ -1 & -2 \end{pmatrix}$. Now when you conjugate by $T$ you will get the matrix that your teacher said should be the answer.